# How to use form:radiobuttons with out model/command object

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, web-applications

I would like to use form:radiobuttons tag from spring form tag lib to get  input form user , but I don't want to use model/command object since this is the only value I get as a input.So I tried below.

JSP:

```
<form action="submitform" method="post" >
<form:radiobuttons path="lang"  items="${languages}"/>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

Controller's method:

```
@RequestMapping("submitform")
public ModelAndView submitForm(@RequestParam("lang") List<String> lang) {
    System.out.println("test:"+lang);
    return new ModelAndView("test", "lang", lang);
}
```

When I submit the form, application throws below error.
HTTP Status 400 - Required List parameter 'lang' is not present.

Can anyone tell me the correct way to do this,I have two below requirements

1.Want to use form:radiobuttons.

2.Don't want to use model/command object.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to use form:radiobuttons with out model/command object

you cannot use *spring's form* elements without having a form backing bean. the *path* attribute of spring's form element tag is supposed to specify the path to the model/command bean's property for data binding.

Spring javadoc have about `<form:radiobuttons` is:

```
| Attribute  | Required? | Runtime Expression? | Description
------------------------------------------------------------
|    path    |  true     |     true            |Path to property for data binding
```

that means, in your case when you don't have model/command bean for data binding, then spring will throw a exception with message as:

```
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'command' available
```

> Can anyone tell me the correct way to do this

use plain HTML radiobuttons in jsp and keep as it all your methods.
in jsp render radiobuttons like:

```
<form action="submitform" method="post" >
    <%-- <form:radiobuttons path="lang"  items="${languages}"/> --%>
    <c:forEach items="${languages}" var="lng">
        <input type="radio"
                name="lang"
                value="${lng}">${lng}
    </c:forEach>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```